# onResume is not calling in the dialog fragment when back press from Another Activity

Tags: android

i' am using an dialog fragment for displaying the details and click a button in the dialog fragment redirect to an Activity and when finish the activity and redirect back to the dialog fragment.but whole devices called onResume but in some device like (Samsung Tab 3 8 inch) calling the on create view again. not calling the onReusme. it cause crash for  me please suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest NOT to assert the dialog will be there when you navigate back from another activity. The system is responsible to recycle any resources (activity, fragment, dialog, etc.) necessary to provide smooth user experience. Even you find a work around, it would be problematic when your app is running on low-memory devices or the device orientation has been changed (so that the whole activity need be re-created).
So, if it's not there, that's OK. Just try to implement the callback to save states (`onSaveInstanceState`) and recover the states in corresponding callbacks (`onCreate`, etc.).

Comment: i did the same but issues is still here i need to call the onResume  other device from tab 3 there is no issue :(

Comment: @RAHULRSANNIDHI any stack trace? So that others could help.

Answer (score 0):

Move the code to onStart(), that way the code should be run every time the Activity becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

finally found the answer this is not the issue with code:) in my testing device i checked the **"Do not keep activities"** in Developer options so this cause the issue. my friend suggest the solution.